# WPF running constantly over 55 fps - still lag in ui

Tags: wpf, performance, canvas, frame-rate

This is a strange issue that I really cant comprehend. I measure fps using the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` method and I have a separate window where I present the current fps - as well as the average over the last 10 seconds. I never drop down below 55fps. However I experience lag in the Visuals that I transform (bound `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on a Visual in a Canvas).

I only update the data for these properties at an interval of 15 fps - this should result in no lag right?

Am I missing something?

TL;DR - I have bound data updating `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on visuals in ~15fps and wpf executes `CompositionTarget.Rendering` in a minimum of 55fps - Still experiencing lag.